# Swift : How can I group or club download items to one cell tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

May be I cannot properly explained it, I have implemented download files mechanism. Files downloading perfectly even URLSession and progress bar works efficiently. I am using TableView for displaying. Image also attached.

**Issue** is I want to club or merge to one download cell. One AppName contains 11 files so it cell displays 11 times. But I want to show it display only once and progress continues until end of files. Instead of 11 cells it should display 1 cell.

How can I achieve this? I am not getting an idea for this?

`fileprivate var fileDownLoadDataArray:[DownLoadData] = []`

```
func detailData(AppId: Int, AppName: String){

        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AppointmentDetail", withExtension: "json") {
            do {

                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(AppointmentDetail.self, from: data)
                self.AppDetailData = jsonData

                for param in AppDetailData?.sectionList ?? [] {
                    for item in param.items! {

                        if item.actionType == 2 {
                            let filename = item.actionUrl ?? ""

                            let data = DownLoadData(with: AppName, and: item.actionUrl ?? "")
                            fileDownLoadDataArray.append(data)
                        }
                    }
                }

            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }

    }
```

Class NSObject

```
class DownLoadData: NSObject {
    var fileTitle: String = ""
    var downloadSource: String = ""
    var downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?
    var taskResumeData: Data?
    var downloadProgress: Float = 0.0
    var isDownloading: Bool = false
    var isDownloadComplete: Bool = false
    var taskIdentifier: Int = 0
    var groupDownloadON:Bool = false
    var groupStopDownloadON:Bool = false

    init(with title:String, and source:String){
        self.fileTitle = title
        self.downloadSource = source
        super.init()

    }
```

TableView DataSource:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fileDownLoadDataArray.count 
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChildTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ChildTableViewCell

        let downloadData = fileDownLoadDataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(with: downloadData)
        cell.cellDelegate = self

        return cell
    }
```

Image:

[image: Download]

Comment: can you show your datasource method for tableview?

Comment: @JohnWick updated code and added tableView methods.

Comment: you are appending data into fileDownLoadDataArray hence the row count is calculating based on array count and that is why you are getting multiple lines. Now you want it on a single view(cell) right? and if yes what is the problem for getting multiple cells?

Comment: Yes exactly you are right but one thing is once its club or grouped to one progress speed also effect which is good. right now every file is downloading so fast.

Comment: For that you need to pass the model data i.e. cell.configureCell(youArray) . also need to do numberOfRows to 1 and Height should be AutoDimension. And in the configureCell function you need a for loop where in you will create the dynamic Label you downloading progressbar blah blah.

Comment: Yes I did that I have passed the model data then it shows me group values but problem is progress still count to first file.  I am struggling with that.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/users come there

Comment: Yes I am there. How can I search you ?

Comment: reputation is not enough apologies . i will let you know the solution after creating a demo for it

Comment: Possible I can share my code? on GitHub  link I have already defined data model

Comment: Link for the project: https://github.com/MasamMahmood/downloadManagerTest

Comment: @JohnWick Is my project accessible to you ?

Comment: yes let me check that

Comment: there are two kind of data one is Melek Mosso and second one is KUĞUKENT_C 2 do you want to display only two rows for that particular projects name?and after clicking on download button only two rows data with detail would be download right?

Comment: Yes right exactly.

Comment: then you have issue with your json you should have one json file while has a child pattern for detail data. can you change your json i.e. for Melek Mosso (it should have data inside the first json)

Comment: First json is `Appointment` in real I pass `appointmentID which is Id` to second json `appointmentDetail`

Comment: Actually I cannot change the json thats the main problem, I have created temp json files for you so you better understand but data is actual like this.

Comment: ok resolved check my answer

Comment: have to updated to Github ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: The result you want]

[image: log file for download file]

What you need to do is to replace your code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.Appdata!.count //Appdata?.count ?? 0
}
```

In cellForRowAt ..

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChildTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ChildTableViewCell
    //let dic = Appdata?[indexPath.row]

    //cell.fileNameLabel.text = dic?.projectName

    let downloadData = fileDownLoadDataArray[indexPath.row]

    let mainProject = self.Appdata![indexPath.row]
    print(mainProject.projectName as Any)

    cell.configureCell(with: downloadData , projectName: mainProject)
    cell.cellDelegate = self

    return cell
}
```

In ConfigureCell

```
 func configureCell(with downloadInfo:DownLoadData, projectName:Appointment){

    // Set the download info into the cell
    self.downloadData = downloadInfo

    fileNameLabel.text = projectName.projectName
    if self.downloadData.groupDownloadON {
        startOrPauseDownload()
        // reset flag
        self.downloadData.groupDownloadON = false
    }
    if self.downloadData.groupStopDownloadON{

        stopDownload()
        self.downloadData.groupStopDownloadON = false
    }
    updateView()


}
```

Hope is that one you are looking for.Cheers

Comment: One thing which I need to ask is it also club/group the downloading time or only appointments display?

Comment: you need to use complition handler for handling downloading time . its just simple data display with download all the child array(which contains URL).

Comment: I am already using handleProgress function if possible can you guide me in that too?

Comment: any chance to get into it ?